# RX java combining observables with one to many relations

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I have an Observer object, which is subscribed on an Observable.
That Observable does an SQL query to DB, gets multiple results and then it does

```
    .forEach(...)
```

Now I need to add a second SQL query to fill that object with more data. This time the result is only one specific value.
I saw there is a zip function, but it does one-to-one pairing according to the documentation. I need to construct object which looks like:

```
    MyObject{
        int i;
        List<AnotherObject>;
    }
```

Comment: Recommended reading: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava#dependent-sub-flows

Comment: So the first `Observable` returns `Observable<AnotherObject>`? And at the end you just want one object that contains a list of every `AnotherObject` emitted by the first `Observable`, plus the result returned by the second query? Does the second query return a `Single` or an `Observable`?

Comment: @dano Yes, the first Observable returns Oservable<AnotherObject>. The second query is what I need to add add now. I can implement however I want, as long as it is stays reactive. BTW the order is not important because the first and the second query do not relay on each other. However both need to update MyObject

Answer (score 0):

You could use `toList()` on the `Observable` returned by the first query, to turn it into a `Single<List>`. Then, you can use `zipWith` to combine that with the result of your second query, which you can make return a `Single`, since it only emits one item.

```java
query1() // Returns Observable<AnotherObject>
  .toList()  // Gives you Single<List<AnotherObject>>
  .zipWith(query2(), (result1, result2) -> new MyObject(result1, result2)))
  ...
```